# How do I make sure my threejs mesh follows my mouse on the x only?

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouseevent

I have a threejs mesh that I want to move from side to side when I move my mouse after clicking it.

On mousemove function here is my code.

The problem I'm running into is if I first move to the right and then I switch directions it doesn't start moving to the left until I get closer to my original x position where I clicked my mouse for the first time.

```
let originx;
onDocumentClick(evt) {
  originx = evt.pageX;
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
}

onMouseMove(evt) {
let _newX = myMesh.position.x + (originx - evt.pageX);
myMesh.position.set(_newX, myMesh.position.y, myMesh.position.z);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear the effect you're trying to achieve, so I'm going to take a stab in the dark... If you update your answer with a more precise description, let me know and I will update this answer.

I think the biggest problem with your logic is that you are basing everything on [`MouseEvent.pageX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX). This property's coordinate system starts at `0` on the left edge, and has a positive value on the right edge. As such, when you move your mouse anywhere to the right of your original click point, you will *always* have a `MouseEvent.pageX` that is *larger* than the `MouseEvent.pageX` of the original point, **regardless of the direction in which you are moving your mouse**. Likewise, `pageX` will only be *smaller* than the original click point's `pageX` value while your cursor is to the left of that click point.

I think the property you're actually looking for is [`MouseEvent.movementX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent). This property describes only the *change* in position since the last `MouseEvent`. It also takes direction into account, so a movement to the right will produce a positive value, and a movement to the left will produce a negative value.

Try replacing `pageX` with `movementX` and see if that gets you closer to what you want.